# Azure Ad Authentication expects me to refresh the main page every few hours

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Recently I moved my Web App to Authenticate using our AzureAD but since then I need to refresh my home page every 1 hour to have it Authenticated else I am getting UnAuthorized Request.

---

I wanted to have this request mainly because I have a **CCTV page** where I will use this page in our common television for our Operation people to view the recent happenings on Onsite (T**his page won't be touched by anytime** and this is just for **viewing purpose**). This CCTV page contains only images and I will **refresh this page every 3 mins** using the following Javascript. So the issue here is

- My CCTV url is **https://app.company.com/cctv** and this page gets the **data from API** **https://app.company.com/api/cctv**. This was working fine until I move to AzureAD. Even in the AzureAD when I first open the page it works perfectly fine. But after around 1 hour **my API returns UnAuthorizedResponse**. Even if I try to refresh this CCTV page **https://app.company.com/cctv** it does not work. **Authentication works only when I refresh the home page** (https://app.company.com). I am not sure why this issue occurs.

> Note: I have my both MVC controller and Web API controller in same
>   project

Please let me know if you can't understand my above explanation.

```
  setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 180000);
```

Comment: Access tokens expire in one hour. What are you using to acquire it? Official libs should handle refresh.

Comment: I use Cookie Authentication for SignIn Web App. Should I have to separatly deal with Refresh Tokens for this?

Comment: Yeah, after you authenticate the user you need to exchange the authorization code for a refresh and access token and store them in a cache. You can use ADAL or MSAL for this purpose. (though you may need to build your own distributed cache there to keep the tokens across instances and restarts).

Comment: I use the following code to setup AzureAD https://imgur.com/a/wjoF4OA. You have any good document which I can refer for this?

Comment: But once again, each refresh of the page should give me a new Token with new expiry right? I am refreshing the page every 3 mins.

Comment: You can see here how they acquire a token after authz code received: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/815dc6748c5664b4398af3dd5fd5e208025631ea/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L63. It's ASPNET Core but can be adapted to OWIN pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using the following code in Authentication Filter when I can't find the user data/profile.

```
  filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

This actually redirects the page to do Authentication when I refresh that page.